# Are only the changes being charged on Firestore onSnapshot?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, snapshot, billing

I have a snapshot listener on my collection.
When I add a document to this collection, every document inside the whole collection gets returned.
Do I have to pay for every document or only 1 read of the newly added document?
I don't understand how the reads are counted for billing in that case.
I would appreciate a link where this behavior is documented.

I am on the blaze plan and I'm not sure if I have to replace the snapshot listeners with regular get() calls to have fewer reads.

If my collection is 100 documents big and I will have to pay for 100 reads on the first load.
Now when I add 1 document, my snapshot listener will return 101 documents and I will have to pay for 100+1 reads.
So in the end I will have paid for 201 reads.
Is this correct?

Comment: Maybe this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-filter-firestore-data-cheaper-705f5efec444) will help you reduce the number of reads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#listens) on this subject say that :

> When you listen to the results of a query, you are charged for a read each time a document in the result set is added or updated. You are also charged for a read when a document is removed from the result set because the document has changed. (In contrast, when a document is deleted, you are not charged for a read.)

So to answer you question, you will get charged for **100+1** reads and not for **201**.